Beta-Bernoulli conjugate prior Bayes risk
Suppose that $X_1,...X_n$ is a sample from Bernoulli distribution with parameter $W$ and prior distribution of $W$ is beta with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
If the loss function is $L(w,d)=(w-d)^2$ then what is the Bayes risk, i.e. $$E\left[Var\left(W|X_1,...X_n\right)\right]$$
The posterior distribution of $W$ is beta with parameters $\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $\beta+n-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.
Also, $E[X_i]=E[E[X_i|W]]=E[W]=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$.
Similarly $E[X_i^2]=E[E[X_i^2|W]]=E[W]=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$.
I'm not sure whether it is correct, I use the fact that the first two moments of Bernoulli distribution with parameter $W$ equal $W$.
Next,
$$E\left[W|X_1,...X_n\right]=\frac{\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\alpha+\beta+n}$$
Method 1
$$Var\left[W|X_1,...X_n\right]=\frac{\left(\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\beta+n-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}$$
$$E\left[Var\left(W|X_1,...X_n\right)\right]=E\left[\frac{\left(\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\beta+n-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}\right]=\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}\left(\alpha(\beta+1)+(\beta+n-\alpha)\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]-E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]\right)=\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}\left(\alpha(\beta+1)+(\beta+n-\alpha)n\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}-n\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right)$$
I've used the fact that $E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^2]$ (due to the independence).
Method 2
Due to the law of the total variance $$E\left[Var\left(W|X_1,...X_n\right)\right]=Var(W)-Var\left[E\left(W|X_1,...X_n\right)\right]=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}-Var\left[\frac{\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\alpha+\beta+n}\right]=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}-\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2}\sum_{i=1}^nVar[X_i]=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}-\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(E[X_i^2]-(E[X_i])^2\right)=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}-\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2}n\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}-\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^2\right)$$
But the final expressions from above two methods are not equal.
Where am I wrong and what is the corret expression for $E\left[Var\left(W|X_1,...X_n\right)\right]$?

Your statement "the fact that $E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^2]$ (due to the independence)" does not look correct to me.

How to solve this problem then?

Let's use $S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ to save typing.  Then

$W$ has a $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ prior distribution with mean $\mathbb E[W]=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}(W)=\frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$

$W$ has a $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha+S,\beta+n-S)$ posterior distribution conditioned on $S$ with mean $\mathbb E[W\mid S]=\frac{\alpha+S}{\alpha+\beta+n}$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}(W\mid S)=\frac{(\alpha+S) (\beta+n-S)}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}$

$S$ has a $\operatorname{Bin}(n, W)$ distribution conditioned on $W$ with mean $\mathbb E[S\mid W]=nW$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}(S\mid W)=nW(1-W)$

$S$ has  $\operatorname{BetaBinomial}(n, \alpha,\beta)$ marginal distribution with mean $\mathbb E[S]=\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}(S)=\frac{n\alpha \beta(\alpha+\beta+n)}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$ so $\mathbb E[S^2]= \frac{na(na+b+n)}{(a+b)(a+b+1)}$

$\operatorname{Var}(W \mid S)=\frac{(\alpha+S)(\beta+n-S)}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)} = \frac{\alpha\beta +n\alpha+(\beta-\alpha+n)S - S^2}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2(\alpha+\beta+n+1)}$

$\mathbb E[\operatorname{Var}(W \mid S) ] = \dfrac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)(\alpha+\beta+n)}.$



As an alternative approach, using the law of total variance
$$\operatorname{Var}(W) = \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(W \mid S)] + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[W \mid S])$$
so $$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(W \mid S)] = \operatorname{Var}(W) - \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[W \mid S])\\
= \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} - \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{\alpha+S}{\alpha+\beta+n}\right)\\
= \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} - \frac{\operatorname{Var}(S)}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2}\\ 
= \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} - \frac{\frac{n\alpha \beta(\alpha+\beta+n)}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}}{(\alpha+\beta+n)^2}\\ 
= \dfrac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)(\alpha+\beta+n)}$$
as before.

Let's test this with a simulation in R:
set.seed(2024)
alpha <- 5
beta <- 2
n <- 3
cases <- 10^7
W <- rbeta(cases, alpha, beta)
S <- rbinom(cases, n, W)
estprobS <- numeric(n+1)        # R starts counting from 1 so offset
varianceWgivenS <- numeric(n+1) 
for (k in 0:n){   
  estprobS[k+1] <- sum(S == k) / cases
  varianceWgivenS[k+1] <- var(W[S == k])
  }
expectedvarianceWgivenS <- sum(varianceWgivenS * estprobS)

with the results
expectedvarianceWgivenS
# 0.01786013
alpha * beta / ((alpha + beta) * (alpha + beta + 1) * (alpha + beta + n))
# 0.01785714

which looks very close, allowing for simulation noise.

How did you get the expression for $Var(S)$?

@PaulR You can look up the variance of a Beta-Binomial distribution, for example on Wikipedia or watch a video.

@PaulR Or you can calculate it from the law of total variance again as $\operatorname{Var}(S) = \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(S \mid W)] + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[S \mid W])$ $= \mathbb{E}[nW(1-W)] + \operatorname{Var}(nW)$ $=n\left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} -\dfrac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} -\dfrac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}\right)+ n^2\dfrac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$ $=\dfrac{n\alpha \beta(\alpha+\beta+n)}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$.

where is the error in the following? $E[S]=E[E[S|W]]=E[nW]=\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$. $E[S^2]=E[E[S^2|W]]=E[nW]=\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$. $Var(S)=E[S^2]-(E[S])^2=\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}-\left(\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^2$.

@PaulR $E[S^2\mid W] \not = nW$ unless $n=1$.  Instead  $E[S^2\mid W]  = nW(1-W)+n^2W^2$ $=nW +n(n-1)W^2$.

Can you clarify how did you get that?

@PaulR $E[S^2\mid W]  =  \operatorname{Var}(S\mid W) +(\mathbb E[S\mid W])^2 $ $= nW(1-W)+n^2W^2$
